# tt_news archive link not being generated

Tags: typo3, tt-news

At the top of my LATEST template I have

```
<!--###LINK_ARCHIVE###-->###GOTOARCHIVE###<!--###LINK_ARCHIVE###-->
```

In my config I have:

```
pid_list = 18
archiveTypoLink.parameter = 86
singlePid = 87
```

Latest, single and list views are all working, but the link archive link is not being displayed. What am I missing! (Thanks!)

Comment: Do you have that first line within the ###TEMPLATE_LATEST### tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. Config values were being defined as constants!

`archiveTypoLink.parameter` is required for the archive link to be rendered.